# Error message Graphics`Colors`

Tags: packages, warning-messages

I am having trouble running this code:

```
Needs["GraphicsColors"];

u[x_, y_] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Re[g[x + iy]], TargetFunctions -> {Im, Re}]];

v[x_, y_] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Im[g[x + iy]], TargetFunctions -> {Im, Re}]];

w[x_, y_] = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[g[x + iy]], TargetFunctions -> {Im, Re}]];

Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
  PlotPoints -> {41, 41}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-0.05, 0.4}},
  ClipFill \[RightArrow] None, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}, 
  ColorFunction -> Hue]; 

Print["u[x,y]=", Re[f[x + iy]]];

Print["=", u[x, y]];
```

When I evaluate the code above, I get the following message:

```
Get::noopen: "Cannot open \!\(\"GraphicsColors\"\). "
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: ``Graphics`Colors`​`` is now a deprecated package. What functions do you need in there?

Comment: To be honest, I need to do what is shown: http://goo.gl/fHvMAb.

Comment: Related: [39386](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39386/error-message-concerning-graphicscolors).

Comment: At the time those pages you referred to were written, you did need to load a package to use `Hue[]` and the named colors; they have been built-in for quite a while, as noted in dionys's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

The message [`Get::noopen`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/Needs/nocont.html) is a warning indicating that your package was not loaded.

This particular package was useful in version 5.2 and earlier, but has been superseded by the functionality built into [`ColorData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorData.html) introduced in version 6. For newer versions of *Mathematica* the colors in the code you're using are available without loading anything extra.

Incidentally, the old colors are still accessible:

```
ColorData["Legacy", "ColorNames"]
(*{"AliceBlue", "AlizarinCrimson", ... ,"YellowOchre", "Zinc"}*)

ColorData["Legacy", "Zinc"] // FullForm
(*RGBColor[0.990005`,0.97`,1.`]*)

Module[{g, u}, g[z_] := 1/(5 z^4 + 26 z^2 + 5);
 u[x_, y_] := Re@g[x + I y];
 Plot3D[u[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 25, 
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-0.05, 0.4}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}, ColorFunction -> Hue]]
```

[image]

Also, the legacy code for the Colors package is still available through the [Wolfram library archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6812/) (MathSource).

Comment: ["Colors.m"](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6812/) should be available, but the link to the file wasn't working when I tested it.